# SQL Server - Automatically full backup for new databases which are auto-created with EntityFramework-Migrations

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, multi-tenant

I have an ASP.NET MVC Application with a Multi-Tenant architecture (using SQL-Server). I'm using EntityFramework DB-Migrations which automatically generates a database per customer.

In SQL-Server I have set up 3 maintenance plans: full, diff and transaction backups. The full-backup happens only once a day.

Now if a new customer-database is auto-generated, the next transaction/differential-backups will fail because there isn't any full-backup available.

I have found following thread with a similar problem: [full-backup-on-database-creation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/239077/full-backup-on-database-creation)

But in this case a full-backup is created for all databases - which could lead to a longer run. I just want to do a full-backup for the new database (which is empty and should be finished within seconds).

I have tried this by extracting the code from the maintenance plan:

```
ON ALL SERVER 
FOR CREATE_DATABASE
AS 

SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @EventData XML = EVENTDATA();
    DECLARE @db sysname = @EventData.value(N'(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', N'sysname');
    DECLARE @SubDir nvarchar(1024) =  N'PATH TO BACKUP-LOCATION' + @db;
    DECLARE @BackupName nvarchar(1024) = @db + N'_backup_initial';
    DECLARE @BakFile nvarchar(1024) = @SubDir + N'\' + @BackupName + N'.bak';
    DECLARE @ErrMessage nvarchar(1024) = N'Verify failed. Backup information for database ' + @db + ' not found';
    declare @backupSetId as int

    EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir @SubDir
    
    exec('BACKUP DATABASE ' + @db + ' TO  DISK = ''' + @BakFile + ''' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = ''' + @BackupName + ''', SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION, ENCRYPTION(ALGORITHM = AES_256, SERVER CERTIFICATE = [BackupCert]),  STATS = 10, CHECKSUM, CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR')
        
    select @backupSetId = position from msdb..backupset where database_name=@db and backup_set_id=(select max(backup_set_id) from msdb..backupset where database_name=@db )
    if @backupSetId is null begin raiserror(@ErrMessage, 16, 1) end
    --RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM  DISK = @BakFile WITH  FILE = @backupSetId,  NOUNLOAD,  NOREWIND
    
GO
```

Executing the backup-script manually is working, but within the trigger it fails with an error message:

> cannot perform a backup or restore operation within a transaction

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: I suggest you read [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2c279d4d-217f-4cc1-86c4-8ba704a645eb/cannot-perform-a-backup-or-restore-operation-within-a-transaction-error-when-restoring-database-on?forum=sqlnetfx).

Comment: Why can't you use the solution of the thread you mentioned with a slightly different code on the trigger to just backup that specific database instead of running the job?

Comment: @Ronaldo: But at the linked thread the trigger just starts a backup job. This will start a full backup for all databases. To use the linked solution I would need do create a job to backup only the new database and inject the name of the newly created DB to the job? I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to get this working?

Don't run it directly from the trigger.  Instead write an Agent job to backup any FULL recovery database that hasn't had a full backup.  This state is sometimes called "[Pseudo-Simple Recovery](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/new-script-is-that-database-really-in-the-full-recovery-mode/)",  as it behaves just like SIMPLE recovery even though the database recovery model has been changed to FULL.

Then either run that every 5 min, kick off the job with [sp_start_job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-start-job-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) from the trigger, or integrate it into your scheduled maintenance so it runs before your log backups.

EG run a cursor over

```
select d.name
from sys.databases d
join sys.database_recovery_status ds
  on d.database_id = ds.database_id
where recovery_model_desc = 'FULL'
and last_log_backup_lsn is null
```

and take full backups.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the snippet. I was able to solve it with this.

Answer (score 4):

my suggestion is to replace your script with one that is using ola hallengren backup solution with the option ChangeBackupType='Y'

https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html

> ChangeBackupType
> Blockquote

> Change the backup type if a differential or
> transaction-log backup cannot be performed.
>
> DatabaseBackup checks differential_base_lsn in
> sys.master_files to determine whether a differential backup can be
> performed. If a differential backup is not possible, then the database
> is skipped by default. Alternatively, you can set ChangeBackupType to
> Y to have a full backup performed instead.
>
> DatabaseBackup checks last_log_backup_lsn in
> sys.database_recovery_status to determine whether a transaction log
> backup in full or bulk-logged recovery model can be performed. If a
> transaction log backup is not possible, then the database is skipped
> by default. Alternatively, you can set ChangeBackupType to Y to have a
> differential or full backup performed instead.

Basically, if you have this set to Y, then when the scheduled tlog for all user_databases runs, then the script will take a full backup instead of just a tlog.